# Manuscript about Jesus by @SLM

Tags: discussion

I [read an answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/63080/10672) where @SLM wrote a 92,000 word manuscript about the life, death, and burial of Jesus. Is there a way to order it?

Comment: Hi Ron, I followed up with @SLM through a comment to [one of his answers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/63080/10672) where he mentioned the manuscript. I realize that since currently you don't have enough points you cannot comment there yet (although you can comment on your own question).  But I'm afraid asking a question like this is not the way to do it. Please take the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: While not the manuscript in question, the LDS have a freely available book [Jesus the Christ, by James E Talmage](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/jesus-the-christ/title-page?lang=eng) (about ~700pg)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking.  My manuscript has not been published, though I tried with the big Christian publishing houses.  I understand they prefer someone who can both write and has a platform.  My next choice is self-publishing, though I have been trying to avoid that.

So, not sure the path forward, but probably it is to put it in book shape (make sure the headings, charts, etc are standard) to self-publish.

Thanks also to GratefulDisciple for making the link.

SLM

Comment: SLM would you mind putting it on a blog spot - or perhaps some other website, like a google doc that we can view?

Comment: @LukeHill  still planning to self-publish.  Putting the finishing touches on it.  The PDF will be about 250 pages.  Not sure if there are limits with a blog or website.

Comment: how do you write that long? I have about a billion thoughts and still struggle to get past the first few pages content wise.

Comment: I wrote on the death, burial, resurrection of Christ what really happened.  I wrote about the period from Moses to the period between the OT and NT to the gospels to Christian history to the meaning.  So, the outline by time helped to keep things organized.  Lots of research.  So, you may put together an outline of some sort.  Write an introduction, maybe 5-10 pages, that summarizes the opening, middle, and ending of what you're doing.  And lastly, go to the library, turn off the internet, and write.  Then do not edit your pages written, until the whole is written.  Good luck!